# Finding unique combinations in a dataset

Tags: r, data.table, combinations

I have the following data set:

```
library(data.table)

dt1 <- data.table(Activity1 = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                  Activity2 = c("B","C","A","C","A","B"),
                  participants = c(12, 22, 4, 20, 3, 31))

# OUTPUT (dt1)
# Activity1 Activity2 participants
# 1:         A         B           12
# 2:         A         C           22
# 3:         B         A            4
# 4:         B         C           20
# 5:         C         A            3
# 6:         C         B           31
```

I am attempting to find all the unique combinations of Activity1 and Activity2 such that I would end up with a dataset looking like the following (that sums the potential participants):

```
# DESIRED Dataset
#    Activity1 Activity2 participants
# 1:         A         B           16
# 2:         A         C           25
# 4:         B         C           51
```

I am still relatively new to R and would appreciate any quidance.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: In addition to the options at the duplicated question, you can also try `pmin` and `pmax`, like: `dt1[, list(participants = sum(participants)), by = list(pmin(Activity1, Activity2), pmax(Activity1, Activity2))]`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto - I don't think that data.table solution over at that duplicate works. The `pmin` and `pmax` are necessary aren't they?

Comment: @thelatemail - I thought that too, but it turns out you've got to run akrun's first two lines to adjust the data frame first, before running `setDT(df)[...]`